# Fast N-Body Simulation with CUDA

Tags: differential-equations, astronomy, cudalink

There is a *Mathematica* code for 3 body simulation

```
data = NBodySimulation["InverseSquare", 
 {<|"Mass" -> 1, "Position" -> {0, 0, 0}, "Velocity" -> {0, 0, 0}|>,
  <|"Mass" -> 2, "Position" -> {1, 1, 1}, "Velocity" -> {0, 0, 0}|>, 
  <|"Mass" -> 3, "Position" -> {1, 1, 0}, "Velocity" -> {0, 0, 0}|>,
  <|"Mass" -> 4, "Position" -> {0, 1, 1}, "Velocity" -> {0, 0, 0}|>}, 1];

Manipulate[ParametricPlot3D[Evaluate[data[All, "Position", t]], {t, 0, k}], {k,0.1, 1}]
```

[image]

How to use *CUDALink* to make a fast "N-Body Simulation with CUDA"?

Thank you in advance to anyone who may be able to give me some ideas

Comment: CUDALink is not for speeding up existing Mathematica functions. You need to implement n-body simulation in C first, for CUDA (which is outside of the scope of this site), then you can use CUDALink to link that up to Mathematica.

Comment: There are code samples available [here](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-samples/index.html#cuda-n-body-simulation) to get you started.